# Inject dependency across a constructor with multiple constructors existing

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop

```
public abstract class MainService<T extends Managed> {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentService.class);
protected final ExecutorService executor;
private final boolean idValidation;

@Autowired
private LockValidator lockValidator;

public MainService() {
    this(null, true);
}

public MainService(boolean idValidation) {
    this(null, idValidation);
}

public MainService(final ThreadConfig tpConfig) {
    this(tpConfig, true);
}

protected MainService(final ThreadConfig tpConfig, final boolean idValidation) {
    
   // Some code

}
```

The code above works fine. But I have to replace the @Autowired annotation and inject the component via constructor. The problem is when I create this constructor:

```
public MainService(LockValidation lockValidation) {
    this.lockValidation = lockValidation;
}
```

Instantly, these attributes get errors:

```
protected final ExecutorService executor;
private final boolean idValidation;
```

> Variable 'executor' might not have been initialized

And of course, I guess that I need to send some parameters into the new constructor. The question is: How Could I refactor this code, using a constructor to inject the component instead of the annotation?

Comment: your code is incomplete, we don't see the line that assign something to `executor`, could you please include it?

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, I updated the code. I can't post all of them for confidentiality.

Comment: Ok, in your new constructor, you need to either call the existing constructor that sets `executor` or you set it directly in the new constructor. You have this error because the field is final and every single constructor **must** initialize this field.

Comment: Yes. In fact I did try to call the constructor with both parameters, but the error persist. Executor is assigned in the main constructor.

Comment: Well add the code where you try with the error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I could see that to create a constructor could be a headache because it's probable to make refactors in the constructors. So, I decided to implement an injection via set method like this:

```
@Autowired
public void setLockValidation(LockValidation lockValidation) {
    this.lockValidation = lockValidation;
}
```

It worked fine

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it simply circumvents it

Comment: Looking at the context, it doesn't. But solved my problem: Maybe this could help to anyone with same circunstances

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:**

```
public MainService(LockValidation lockValidation,ThreadConfig tpConfig,boolean idValidation) {
        this(tpConfig,idValidation);
        this.lockValidation = lockValidation;
    }
```

You are not following **SOLID** principles (`Dependency Injection`) here by initializing `executor` inside the constructor. Best approach would be to use `all argument` constructor.

```
protected MainService(ThreadConfig tpConfig,boolean idValidation,ExecutorService executor,LockValidation lockValidation) {
    this.tpConfig=tpConfig;
    this.idValidation=idValidation;
    this.executor=executor;
    this.lockValidation=lockValidation;
       /// Some code
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sadly it didn't work. NullPointerException

Comment: it marks an error over this.executor:
`_Variable 'executor' might already have been assigned to_`

Comment: Have you already assigned value to `executor` in `MainService(final ThreadConfig tpConfig, final boolean idValidation)` constructor ?

Comment: Yes, executor has a value inside

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope this will be helpful

Comment: Yeah, I got it. This software is working like this. I did not code this one. I'm, just refactoring the code where @Autowired is used and I'm updating them to use constructor as well. This case is confusing to me, because I always use the first example you shared.

Comment: Also, executor is not the dependency to inject. This variable is set depending of tpConfig value. lockValidation is the value to inject

Comment: You can then stick with quick fix

Comment: `You are not following SOLID principles (Dependency Injection) here by initializing executor inside the constructor. Best approach would be to use all argument constructor.` -- Well we don't have enough context to judge on that, you don't always want to inject everything

Comment: May I know for which variable you are  getting `NullPointerException` ?  Are you providing `tpConfig` object to constructor?

Comment: Sure, I'm getting nullpointer on every service that calls this Service ( another services extends this one to use create, save, update, etc ) it's a huge list. Everything goes fine if I keep the @Autowired.